# dockerized postgresql with volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker, volumes

i am relatively new to docker. I'd like to set up a postgres database but I wonder how to make sure that the data isn't being lost if I recreated the container.

Then I stumbled over named volumes (not bind volumes) and how to use them.
But... in a Dockerfile you can't use named volumes.  E.g. data:/var/lib etc.
As I understood using a Dockerfile it's always an anonymous volume.
So every single time I'd recreate a container it would get its 
own new volume.

So here comes my question:

Firstly: how do I make sure, if the container get's updated or recreated that the postgres database from within the new container references to the same data and not losing the reference to the previously created anonymous volume.

Secondly: how does this work with a yml file?
is it possible to reference multiple replicas of such a database container to one volume? (High Availability Mode)?

It would really be great if someone could get me a hint or best practices.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the Dockerfile for [Postgres](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/1805adb0693d9602bfb19b6bf2583b311c43b749/10/Dockerfile), you see that it declares a volume instruction:

```
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Everytime you run a new Postgres container, without specifying a `--volume` option, docker automatically creates a new volume. The volume is given a random name.

You can see all volumes by running the command:

```
docker volume ls
```

You can also inspect the files stored on the host by the volume, by inspecting the host path using:

```
docker volume inspect <volume-name>
```

So when you don't specify the `--volume` option for the run command, docker create volumes for all volumes declared in the Dockerfile. This is mainly a safety if you forget to name your volume and the data shouldn't be lost.

> Firstly: how do I make sure, if the container get's updated or
>   recreated that the postgres database from within the new container
>   references to the same data and not losing the reference to the
>   previously created anonymous volume.

If you want docker to use the same volume, you need to specify the `--volume` option. Once specified, docker won't create a new volume and it will simply mount the existing volume onto the specified folder in the docker command.

As a best practice, name your volumes that have valuable data. For example:

```
docker run --volume postgresData:/var/lib/postgresql/data ...
```

If you run this command for the first time the volume `postgresData` will be created and will backup `/var/lib/postgresql/data` on the host. The second time you run it the same data backed up on the host will be mounted onto the container.

> Secondly: how does this work with a yml file? is it possible to
>   reference multiple replicas of such a database container to one
>   volume?

Yes, volumes can be shared between multiple containers. You can mount the same volume onto multiple containers, and the containers will use the same files. Docker compose allows you to do that ...

However, beware that volumes are limited to the host they were created. When running containers on multiple machines, the volume needs to be accessible from all the machines. There are ways/tools to achieve that 
but they are a bit complex. This is still a limitation to be addressed in Docker.

Comment: thanks yamenk for your great answer. I'd like to go the latter way. But if I'd use a yml file to run my containers I have no such an option to declare a named volume. By running 'docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml postgres' what do I have to declare to have a named volume though?

Comment: @Chris you can specify a named data volume as specified in https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3. `postgresData:/var/lib/postgresql/data`